# Axios throws self signed certificate error in asyncData (nuxt)

Tags: ssl, vue.js, https, axios, nuxt.js

I am working on a project and I am using `nuxt` for it. API calls are being made to `node.js` server over `https`, and since everything is in my local development, I am using `self signed certificates`.

When I try to make `axios` call from `asyncData`, I receive

```
 ERROR  self signed certificate                                                                                                                                                                        15:08:11

  at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1049:34)
  at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
  at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
  at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:631:8)
```

Same error shows when i try to make `axios` call from  `nuxtServerInit` . 
Identical call made from `methods` and called with `@click` gets the data and works. Also, other calls in `store actions` also work without issues.

Is there a reason why this calls don't work, and also, is there a way to make axios calls as described above?

this doesn't work:

```
async asyncData(context) {
    let result = await context.app.$axios.$get("/item", {
      headers: {
        "x-auth": context.store.getters["login/getToken"]
      }
    });       
    console.log("item: ", result.item);
  }
```

and this does work without problems:

```
methods: {
  async getItem() {
    try {
      let result = await this.$axios.$get("/item", {
        headers: {
          "x-auth": this.$store.getters["login/getToken"]
        }
      });      
      console.log("item : ", result.item);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for help

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No, i continued working for a while on a project without https because i couldnt get it to work, and than gave it all up using nuxt and im now swapped back to vue.js without nuxt.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by using this configuration when setting up Axios:

```
$axios.defaults.httpsAgent = new HttpsAgent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false
});
```

Note: this might be pretty security critical whereby this config should only be triggered when necessary (local development).