# @nuxtjs/auth Why refresh page always redirect to login

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I can't refresh page or open new tab of secure page after refresh or new tab will redirect me to login 
again

**Version**

```
Nuxt.js v2.9.1
@nuxtjs/module: 4.8.4
```

**secure page**

```
middleware: ['auth'],
```

*middleware of auth-module*

**login page**

```
middleware: ['guest'],
```

**middleware/guest.js**

```
export default async function({ store, redirect }) {
    // console.log(store.state.auth)
    if (store.state.auth.loggedIn) {
        return redirect('/')
    }
}
```

*console.log(store.state.auth) = { user: null, loggedIn: false, strategy: 'local' }*

**nuxt.config.js**

```
auth: {
        strategies: {
            local: {
                endpoints: {
                    // register: { url: 'member', method: 'post', propertyName: 'data.accessToken' },
                    login: { url: 'api/authen-admin', method: 'post', propertyName: 'custom' },
                    user: { url: 'api/admin', method: 'get', propertyName: 'custom' },
                    logout: false
                },
                tokenRequired: 'Authorization',
                tokenType: false
            }
        },
        watchLoggedIn: true,
        localStorage: {
            prefix: 'auth.'
        },
        cookie: {
            prefix: 'auth.', // Default token prefix used in building a key for token storage in the browser's localStorage.
            options: {
                path: '/', // Path where the cookie is visible. Default is '/'.
                expires: 5 // Can be used to specify cookie lifetime in Number of days or specific Date. Default is session only.
                    // domain: '', // Domain (and by extension subdomain/s) where the cookie is visible. Default is domain and all subdomains.
                    // secure - false, // Sets whether the cookie requires a secure protocol (https). Default is false, should be set to true if possible.
            }
        },
        redirect: {
            login: '/login',
            logout: '/login',
            home: '/'
        },
        resetOnError: true
}
```

I try to use **vuex-persist** to persist local storage but doesn't work and when login not redirect to home path still stay login path

Comment: Hey!  this is Jeffrey from @VueScreencasts.  Thanks for making this and adding the code.

"I try to use vuex-persist to persist local storage but doesn't work" - Two thoughts:

1. I didn't have to use an extra library to make localstorage or cookies persist.  Could vuex-persist be interfering?

2. What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Is it not storing cookies at all? Or is it storing cookies but not sending them to the server?  Or is it sending them to the server, but the authentication is wrong?

Comment: @JeffreyBiles 
1. I don't use extra library to make localstrorage or cookies same like you.
2. "doesn't work" it mean when i use vuex-persist @nuxtjs/auth not redirect when login success but uninstall vuex-persist then @nuxtjs/auth redirect when login success

Comment: "Vuex-persist" is the extra library, and since it works when you uninstall vuex-persist, I think we have our answer.  If you need to use vuex-persist for other things, then you should ask someone who's used that library before, since the bug seems to be in vuex-persist rather than Nuxt Auth.

Comment: Sorry to make you confuse, When i use only Nuxt Auth it don't work it can't refresh page then i try to use "Vuex-persist" to persist localstorage or cookie then state not empty but bug with nuxt auth when login success nuxt auth can't redirect to secure page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe you can use `nuxtServerInit` to check the login user. place in the `store/index.js` folder as root folder. every time you open the web for the first time, this code will run. example i use the cookie to check user loggedIn or not:

```
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
    let auth = null
    if (req.headers.cookie) {
      // cookie found
      try {
        // check data user login with cookie
        const { data } = await this.$axios.post('/api/auths/me')
        // server return the data is cookie valid loggedIn is true
        auth = data // set the data auth
      } catch (err) {
        // No valid cookie found
        auth = null
      }
    }
    commit('SET_AUTH', auth) // set state auth
  },
}
```

[here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action) the documentation

Answer (score 3):

Extending Fauzan Edris answer.

I was using Auth Nuxt, following fixed my issue.

```
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit({
    commit
  }, {
    req
  }) {
    let auth = null
    if (req.headers.cookie) {
      // cookie found
      try {
        // check data user login with cookie
        const {
          data
        } = await this.$axios.post('/user/profile')
        // server return the data is cookie valid loggedIn is true
        auth = data.data // set the data auth
      } catch (err) {
        // No valid cookie found
        auth = null
      }
    }

    // How we can set the user for AuthNuxt
    // Source: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth
    this.$auth.setUser(auth)
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `propertyName` of user endpoint to `'custom'`, do you receive the response with this property name? when page reload, auth plugin will try to `fetchUser` method to sure client still authenticated, if you didnt config user endpoint correctly, regardless of whether receive, user will set null, so you will redirect to login page, you can check what user property set by run this code:

```
let user = await this.$auth.requestWith(
    'local', null, { url: 'api/admin', method: 'get', propertyName: 'custom' } );
console.log(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Nuxt with Laravel Sanctum and the thing that solved the problem for me was an issue with the SESSION_DOMAIN. I'm running the project on a subdomain and the SESSIOn_DOMAIN was set to ".domain.com", but it has to be set to "sub.domain.com".

Answer (score 0):

I've got same and find out on server message, that looked impossible

```
[404] /api/admin
```

So I've tried to add BASE_URL to this request url into nuxt.config.js

```
auth: {
  strategies: {
    local: {
      endpoints: {
        user: { url: `${BASE_URL}/api/admin`, ... },
    ...
}
```

and issue gone

Answer (score 0):

After using Fauzan Edris' answer and zarpio's comment (both REALLY useful, thanks!), I was able to proceed with this issue.

But my call using axios failed because I use a self signed certificate:

```
self signed certificate

  at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1502:34)
  at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
  at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:937:8)
  at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:711:12)
```

Then, after reading [this](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/6559#issuecomment-541926588) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76079377/4187360), I managed to resolve it, for example:

```
// plugins/axios.js

import https from 'https';

export default function ({ $axios, redirect }) {

  // I want to ignore SSL errors on TEST ONLY (and dev too), because I will use a self-signed certificate there
  if (process.env.APP_ENVIRONMENT !== 'production') {
    $axios.defaults.httpsAgent = new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false });
  }

// other stuff ...

}
```

```
// nuxt.config.js

// ...

auth: {
    redirect: {
      // ...
    },
    strategies: {
      // ...
    },
    plugins: [
      {
        src: '~/plugins/axios',
        ssr: true
      }
    ]
  },

// ...
```